# Как запаковать файлы в tar архив игнорируя каталог?

Tags: linux, tar

Я просто поражён, что за всё это время в интернете нет информации о том, как это сделать. Или я просто плохо ищу. Допустим у менять есть такая структура:

```
dist/file1
dist/file2
dist/file3
```

Я хочу чтобы все 3 файла, которые находятся внутри dist оказались в архиве. Это можно сделать так:

```
tar -cf dist.tar dist
```

Но тогда в архив попадёт сам каталог dist, а я этого не хочу, мне нужны только файлы внутри архива без каталога. Я пробовал:

```
tar -cf dist.tar dist/
tar -cf dist.tar dist/*
cd dist; tar -cf dist.tar ./
```

Но всё это не работает либо делает не то, что мне нужно. Неужели нет адекватного способа сделать это не перечисляя все файлы??

Comment: `tar -cf dist.tar -C dist .` (хотя это создаст в архиве папку с точкой в названии; не знаю, является ли это проблемой)

Comment: @andreymal Да я уже приходил к такому решению, оно не подходит)

Comment: Почему не подходит?

Comment: Попробуйте `cd dist; tar cf ../dist.tar *` Если нужно будет добавить потом файлы из другого каталога -- `cd ../dist2; tar --append -f ../dist.tar *`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Неужели нет адекватного способа сделать это не перечисляя все файлы?

адекватного способа сделать неадекватное (по-русски — несоответствующее) общепринятой практике — действительно нет.

для того, чтобы  при **разархивировании** пропустить несколько уровней каталогов, служит опция `--strip-components=число`. это достаточно соответствует общепринятой практике.

---

пример: имеется архив с такой структурой внутри:

```
каталог1/
├── файл1
└── файл2
```

чтобы извлечь файлы, например, в текущий каталог, без создания `каталога1`:

```
$ tar -x архив --strip-components=1
```

---

а если всё-таки требуется сделать не очень соответствующее общепринятой практике, то при создании архива можно воспользоваться, например, опцией `-T файл.со.списком`, только в качестве файла передать файловый дескриптор со списком (если используемая оболочка такое умеет. программа *bash*, например, — умеет):

```
$ tar -cf архив -C каталог1 -T <(cd каталог1 && ls)
$ tar -tf архив
файл1
файл2
```

---

на тот случай, если используемая оболочка не умеет передавать файловые дексрипторы, можно либо подготовить список заранее (и указать в опции `-T список` имя этого файла со списком), либо сформировать список динамически и передать на *stdin* программе *tar* (указав `-` как имя файла в опции `-T список`):

```
$ (cd каталог1 && ls) | tar -cf архив -C каталог1 -T -
```

Comment: Исправьте, пожалуйста опечатку во флаге в команде `tar -x `, мне говорить мол правка должна быть не менее 6 символов

Comment: спасибо. исправил.